# How can I remove a element when another appear?

Tags: jquery, validation, materialize

I use MaterializeCSS to display an email form and when the email validation failed, I would like to hide a "clue" element.

```css
.input-field .clue {
 color: #666;
 font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
 margin-top:-0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form id="testForm">
<div class="input-field">
<input id="email" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="email" data-error="wrong email adress" data-success="right">Email</label>
<p id="clue-email" class="clue">We don't spam, never !</p>
</div>
</form>
```

If you try to input "test" as email adress, the warning message and the clue message are mixed. I would like to hide the clue message ("We don't spam, never !") when the warning message appear ("wrong email adress")

I don't know if I should do this in pure CSS or in Jquery.

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Axel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `input` gets `invalid` or `valid` class, you can add the following CSS rule, which hides all items having `hide-on-input-message` class which are located after `input` in the same `input-field`:

```
.input-field input.invalid ~ .hide-on-input-message, 
.input-field input.valid ~ .hide-on-input-message 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Updated snippet:

```css
.input-field .clue {
 color: #666;
 font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
 margin-top:-0.8rem;
}

.input-field input.invalid ~ .hide-on-input-message, .input-field input.valid ~ .hide-on-input-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<form id="testForm">
<div class="input-field">
<input id="email" type="email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
<label for="email" data-error="wrong email adress" data-success="right">Email</label>
<p id="clue-email" class="clue hide-on-input-message">We don't spam, never !</p>
</div>
</form>
```